# Forward my received Facebook messages (chat + messages) to my email inbox, and subsequently delete them from my Facebook inbox

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-chat, facebook-messages

Facebook does not offer a feature which forwards ALL my received messages to my email inbox, and subsequently deletes them from my facebook inbox. Is there an existing application or online service which offers this functionality? If no:

I want to write a script which does exactly that. It should poll regularly if a new message has arrived. If yes, it should forward it to my email address and delete it from my FB inbox automatically, without user interaction.

Which scripting languages are suited for that task, which classes and methods? Is it advisable to move that script to a web server so it runs continuously without user interaction? How can one go about that?

Comment: I understand that there is no elegant way to do this with the Facebook API. However, as a user can manually delete their Facebook Messages, there must be a way to automate this process. As a last resort, I am thinking of a macro environment (eg. [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org)) which is capable of image recognition that just looks for the correct button and clicks it.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not delete anything, only you can delete inbox messages.

Anyway, what you are trying to achieve is not possible, access to the inbox is not possible anymore. Facebook removed the API endpoint for it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use facebook graph extended permissions "read_mailbox" to read the facebook messages.
Please note that this extended permission is available only for facebook graph API version 2.3 (not available for version 2.4 and up).

You can read the facebook messages every 5/10 minutes (via graph API) and in the case of a new message you can create a new self email message with the facebook message.
You will NOT be able to delete the facebook message (read mode only)

Hope this helps. 
Good luck!